# Rxjava - chain observables

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2, flatmap

Please look at this code:

```
 Disposable disposable = mcityService.authLogin(request,Utils.prepareHeaders())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(resp ->
                {
                    mCompositeDisposable.add(mcityService.getUserDetails(selectedCity.id,Utils.prepareHeaders(resp.tokenType,resp.accessToken))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(userDetails ->
                            {
                                /*process resp and user details*/

                            }));


                }, throwable ->
                {
                    process errors
                });

        mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);
    }
```

So basically I need to call `authLogin`, if it succedes, call `getUserDetails` (some fields from `authLogin` call results are required), if `getUserDetails` succeded, chain is finished and I need some additional processing result from both calls. If `authLogin` fails or `getUserDetails` fails, error processing should be performed (for example, get http error code or message from throwable).

As my approach works, I know it's not goot approach, how to optimize it? Can I use `flatMap` operator instead nested observables?

edit: Methods declarations:

```
public static Map<String, String> prepareHeaders(String tokenType, String accessToken);
Observable<UserDetails> getUserDetails(@Path(value = "cityId", encoded = true) String cityId, @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers);
```

Final attempt:

```
mcityService.authLogin(request, Utils.prepareHeaders())
                .concatMap(response ->
                {
                    final Map<String, String> headers = Utils.prepareHeaders(response.tokenType,response.accessToken);
                    return mcityService.getUserDetails(selectedCity.id, headers)
                            .map(userDetails -> new Object()
                            {
                                public AuthResponse ar = response;
                                public UserDetails ud = userDetails;
                            });
                })
                .doOnNext(responseDetails ->
                {
                   AuthResponse ar = responseDetails.ar;  
                   UserDetails ud = responseDetails.ud;   


                })
                .doOnError(throwable ->
                {

                    final String message = throwable.getMessage();

                });
```

Results: `.doOnNext` never called, `mcityService.getUserDetails` seems to be never called, `.doOnError` also never called (so there was no error). First `mcityService.authLogin` call returns `Observable<AuthResponse>` don't I really need `subscribe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, and should use `flatMap` / `concatMap` / `switchMap`.
Also, sorry if it is not coded well, I primarily use RxJS, which has pipable operators (much better!).

```
mcityService.authLogin(request, Utils.prepareHeaders())
            .concatMap(response -> { 
               final Map<String, String> headers = Utils.prepareHeaders(resp.tokenType,resp.accessToken);
               return mcityService.getUserDetails(selectedCity.id, headers)
                                  .map(userDetails -> ResponseUserDetails.of(response, userDetails));
            })
            .doOnNext(responseDetails -> {
               // Hanlde ResponseUserDetails object
            })
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
               // Handle exception
               final String message = throwable.getMessage();
               ...
            })
            .subscribe(
               responseDetails -> { ... },
               throwable -> { ... }
            );
```

---

If you don't want to use an additional class, you can create an `Object` on the fly

```
return mcityService.getUserDetails(selectedCity.id, headers)
                   .map(userDetails -> new Object() { 
                           public Response r = response;
                           public UserDetails ud = userDetails;
                   });
```

And access its fields via

```
.doOnNext(responseDetails -> {
     final Response r = responseDetails.r;
     final UserDetails ud = responseDetails.ud;
     ...
})
```

---

```
static class ResponseUserDetails {
   final Response response;
   final UserDetails userDetails;

   ResponseUserDetails(
            final Response response,
            final UserDetails userDetails) {
      this.response = response;
      this.userDetails = userDetails;
   }

   static ResponseUserDetails of(
            final Response response,
            final UserDetails userDetails) {
      return new ResponseUserDetails(response, userDetails);
   }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190532/discussion-on-answer-by-lppedd-rxjava-chain-observables).

Comment: Hello, do you have any example to chain 3 calls?